# Trying to execute of a child element inside a parent array java

Tags: java, arrays

I have three classes.

```
public class PutController{ 
    public PutController[] putControllerArray = new PutController[2];
    public void controlar(int players) {
        if(numeroJugadores==0){
        putControllerArray[0] = new PutAutoController(tablero, tableroView, turno, turnoView);
        putControllerArray[1] = new PutAutoController(tablero, tableroView, turno, turnoView);
        }
        if(numeroJugadores==1){
            putControllerArray[0] = new PutManualController(tablero, tableroView, turno, turnoView);
            putControllerArray[1] = new PutAutoController(tablero, tableroView, turno, turnoView);
        }
    }
}

public class PutManualController extends PutController {
    public void methodToCall(){
     .....
    }
}

public class PutAutoController extends PutController {
     public void methodToCall(){
      .....
     }
}

class Principal{
    private PutController putController = new PutController(tablero, tableroView, turno, turnoView);
}
```

and in my Principal class i want to call a method of an element in the array of put class, like this.

```
putController.putControllerArray[0].methodToCall();
```

Hope you can help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as `PutController` contains the method `methodToCall()` (either as an abstract method implemented by the sub classes, or with a concrete implementation in the base class), you can call it on any element of your array.

```
public class PutController
{ 
...
    public void methodToCall ()
    {
        ....
    }
...
}
```

The sub-classes can override `methodToCall()` if they require different implementations.

This would make the code `putControllerArray[0].methodToCall()` valid. Of course, if you need to access that array from outside your class, you need to create an instance of your class, since it's not a static member. It would be better, though, to make the array private and access it via a method that returns the i'th element of the array.

```
public class PutController
{ 
...
    public PutController getElement (int i)
    {
        if (i < 0 || i >= putControllerArray.length) {
            // TODO throw some exception
        }
        return putControllerArray[i];
    }
...
}
```

Then you can execute `methodToCall()` via `putController.getElement(0).methodToCall();`

Comment: I try to do something like that but i didn't get it correctly. Can you help me with an example please?

Comment: @RodrigoLópez Not sure where you got a problem, but added an example.